# Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

When trying to plot a heatmap in r Markdown I am able to produce a html file, but each time my pdf file fails due to margins being to large.

A repoducable section of code, including pre-amble etc is shown below

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  bookdown::html_document2: 
   theme: darkly
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
   keep_tex: TRUE
   number_sections: TRUE
   toc: FALSE
fontsize: 11pt
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
  rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding,
  output_format = "all") })
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(results = 'hide')
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.pos = 'H')
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.align = 'center')
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
```{r cars}
x = matrix(runif(400), ncol = 20)
heatmap3::heatmap3(x)
```
````

So far I have set `par(mar)` to a wide range of numbers from `c(1,1,1,1)` to `c(10,10,10,10)` as well as the `margin` command in the `heatmap3` command, all of which fail.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Please note, this is not a duplicate question of a standard "figure margins too large" error as it is localised only to the pdf, but works fine as html or just in the console.

Comment: Not sure if your `bookdown::pdf_document2:` should be indented like that, maybe just a format error?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Issue with copying over and indenting here but is correct in the code

Answer (score 0):

Simply include:

```
par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Comment: Might help with some figures, but some figures are still too large.